# How do I use a string as python function syntax?

Tags: python, string, function, dataframe, filter

`dfm` is the dataframe parameter in the function. I need to assign `col_string` as a string of a column name in my dataframe, but when I execute my filtration, the function is reading `col_string` as a string instead of actual function syntax.

```
def the_function(dfm, col_string, filt_string):
    filtered_df = dfm[dfm.col_string == filt_string]
    print(filtered_df)

the_function(df, 'Name', 'Zero')
```

Comment: please show your code, so we can properly evaluate

Comment: Hi, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and do edits in your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For variables you need to use the bracket notation

```
filtered_df = dfm[dfm[col_string] == filt_string] 
print(filtered_df)
```